# Creating a dictionary from a .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a login system for a whole bunch of students, where the data is provided by a text file in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "clave": "f22LwdI",
    "alumno": "SI",
    "nombre": "Samuel Riquelme"
  },
  {
    "clave": "KaEEkNjFz",
    "alumno": "NO",
    "nombre": "Paulina Toro",
  }
]
```

I've tried several text reading functions without success. So that's why I decided to bring this here.

In this case I need to instantiate 2 different users and read the file in order to make this possible.

Comment: That's JSON. Use the `json` module.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

# or read that string in from the file with something like
# with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
#     strg = file.read()
strg = '''[ { "clave": "f22LwdI", "alumno": "SI", "nombre": "Samuel Riquelme" },
    { "clave": "KaEEkNjFz", "alumno": "NO", "nombre": "Paulina Toro", } ]'''

lst = literal_eval(strg)
print(lst[0]['clave'])
```

note that the returned object is a list of dictionaries.

now that the formatting of your question has been updated: your format is (almost) json; if you correct the superfluous comma at the end of the second dictionary you could do this:

```
import json

strg = '''[
  {
    "clave": "f22LwdI",
    "alumno": "SI",
    "nombre": "Samuel Riquelme"
  },
  {
    "clave": "KaEEkNjFz",
    "alumno": "NO",
    "nombre": "Paulina Toro"
  }
]'''

lst = json.loads(strg)
print(lst)
print(lst[1])
```